# How to post data by business central POST API using PHP

Tags: php, api, stored-procedures, dynamics-business-central

I'm trying to update the status of the payment recieved from a PHP webpage to the business central using a business central POST API.

Here is the code that I'm trying:

```
<?php
$username="username";
$password="password";
$url="API_URL";

$postData = '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/WebServiceUpdate">
            <sONo>101007</sONo>
        </UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus>
    </Body>
</Envelope>';


$headers = array(
                        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                        "Accept: text/xml",
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                        "Pragma: no-cache",
                        "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password")
                    );

$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'  => $headers,
            'content' => $postData
        )
    ));
$response = file_get_contents($url, false , $context);


if($response === FALSE){
        die('Error');
    }
    else
    {
        echo $response;
    }
```

I'm getting a blank page with to boxes. When I do the inspect element then the page has some XML content as a code.

I have tried the API with the Wizdler extension in Chrome it worked well. But if I try the same API with postman it returns the same XML content as a output.

Output XML content is as follows:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/WebServiceUpdate" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/WebServiceUpdate">
    <types>
        <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/WebServiceUpdate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <element name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sONo" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus"/>
    </message>
    <message name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus_Result"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="WebServiceUpdate_Port">
        <operation name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus">
            <input name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus" message="tns:UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus"/>
            <output name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus_Result" message="tns:UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus_Result"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="WebServiceUpdate_Binding" type="tns:WebServiceUpdate_Port">
        <binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        <operation name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/WebServiceUpdate:UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus" style="document" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="UpdateSalesOrderPaymentStatus_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="WebServiceUpdate">
        <port name="WebServiceUpdate_Port" binding="tns:WebServiceUpdate_Binding">
            <address location="https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/e95a69fe-37bd-407a-a394-45d3aa91f45a/Sandbox/WS/Hickey%20Metal%20Fabrication/Codeunit/WebServiceUpdate?tenant=msocna4832t93425692&amp;aid=FIN" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

plz help out where I'm doing wrong, I'm interacting with Business central API for the first time .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this content-type in the header:

"Content-type: application/xml"

You can probably remove "Accept" parameter as well.